# Filtering data in Logstatsh

Tags: filter, config, logstash

I am currently using the following filter in my logstash setup:

```
filter {
  if [type] == "can_robbery" {
    csv {
      columns => ["Date","Time","Transit","Region","Address","City","Province","Postal Code","Country","Robbery Type","Amt Stolen","Recovery Amt","Net Loss","Dye Pac","GPS Given?","Dye Pack Success (Arrest/Stained Money)","Decoy","Weapon Displayed","Follow Robbery Guidelines","Guard/Greeter","Cash Platform Analysis","Aggressive","Arrest Info (from donna)","# of Suspects","# Rob in 2 yrs","Crime Risk","Multi-Robbery with same suspect","Disguise","Employee Related","AMIS","Weapon Used? [Y/N]","Decoy (Given Count)","DyePac (Given Count)","GPS Given","Ancillary used?","Notes"]
      separator => ","
    }

    mutate {
      replace => [ "date" , "%{Date} %{Time}" ]
    }
  }
}
```

What I am getting is:

"@timestamp": "2014-11-18T16:32:48.807Z",

"type": "can_robbery",

"host": "digitalevidence-ThinkCentre-M58p",

"path": "/home/digitalevidence/temp/canada/robbery.csv",

"Date": "9/29/2014",

"Time": "17:50:00",

What I want is:

"@timestamp": "2014-09-29T17:50:00.000Z",

"type": "can_robbery",

"host": "digitalevidence-ThinkCentre-M58p",

"path": "/home/digitalevidence/temp/canada/robbery.csv",

"Date": "9/29/2014",

"Time": "17:50:00",

What changes do I need in my filter configuration file?

Comment: Ca you put one of your input string log message ? IT will be helpful to debug it. Besides, you need to use `date` filter from logstash if you want to change the time on timestamp value.

Comment: I have a csv file with line entries consisting of (example): 

11/30/2013,10:31:00,1198,GTA ,80 FRONT ST E,Toronto,ON,M5E,Canada,Verbal,200,0,200,N/G,,No Opportunity,N/G,None,Yes - Could done better,None,SD-CDU,,Y,1,0,Medium,,Y,,Y,N,0,0,0,0,"description and notes go here"

I want to use the date and time in the first two columns as the @timestamp in my logstash

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to start is to combine the Date and Time fields into one, like you're doing.  I would have just used add_field and with a more distinct field name:

```
mutate {
  add_field => [ "myDateTime" , "%{Date} %{Time}" ]
}
```

This field would then look like:  9/29/2014 17:50:00

Then, you can use the date filter to replace the @timestamp field with your new value.

```
date {
  match => [ "myDateTime", "mm/dd/YYYY HH:mm:ss" ]
}
```

(I'm not 100% on the pattern, but it's close).

If you don't need myDateTime after this, you can remove it.